# How to keep Remote Machine always alive for Execution of Automation Execution

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline, remote-desktop

How to keep Remote Machine always alive for Execution of Automation Execution.

We trigger Jenkins Pipeline on the Remote Windows 10 Virtual Machine. It goes to sleep and Automation fails as at that moment it is not available what can be done to keep it working 24*7. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in [Configure Timeout and Reconnection Settings for Remote Desktop Services Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754272(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) <sup>**1**</sup> you can configure the below mentioned timeout and reconnection settings in Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.

**Active session limit**

> Specify the maximum amount of time that the user's Remote Desktop Services session can be active before the session is automatically disconnected or ended.
>
> The user receives a warning two minutes before the Remote Desktop Services session is disconnected or ended, which allows the user to save open files and close programs.

**Idle session limit**

> Specify the maximum amount of time that an active Remote Desktop Services session can be idle (without user input) before the session is automatically disconnected or ended.
>
> The user receives a warning two minutes before the session is disconnected or ended, which allows the user to press a key or move the mouse to keep the session active.

---

### Legends

1. Applies to Windows Server 2008 R2